# Fewer than expected Rows INSERTED

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using this query to return results from the said table and insert in SalesReason Table. 
When i only run the select part of the statement the rows returned are > 8000 but 
when i use it with insert as shown below i only get 3 rows inserted in the table. 
Why and whats happening?

```
INSERT INTO dp_stg_sales.SalesReason (SalesReasonID, TeamName, ReasonType)
SELECT (CASE WHEN SalesReasonID_One = 'NULL' THEN 0 
             ELSE CAST(SalesReasonID_One AS  INTEGER) 
        END) AS SalesReasonID,
       Name_One, 
       ReasonType 
FROM dp_stg_sales.Sales_April_Part1_Filtered
```

EDIT :
This the result of Select statement [SelectStatementResult](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2NHcLi1fg7NZ0xRT2drYTNkX2s)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: Click edit, then scroll down to the tag section (it is below the question body area).  Add a tag for your database (ie MySQL, SQL Server)

Comment: Do you have any trigger on SalesReason table?

Comment: @sarslan No, I only created the table and was trying to insert data into it

Comment: Post the actual execution plan for the insert as XML. E.g. To https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: do you have `set rowcount 3` or something similar being set before the insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many duplicate rows in the `SELECT` query results. It seems the `dp_stg_sales.SalesReason` has a unique index created with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` option so only unique key values that don't already exist in the table are inserted.

Comment: You are absolutely correct sir, basically i am working with Teradata, and by default if not mentioned otherwise all tables are SET Tables(no duplicates allowed), so resolved that issue by adding MULTISET when creating table

Comment: Why did you tag the question SQL Server if it is Teradata?

Comment: @umair.ashfr: Switching to `MULISET` will insert all those duplicate rows, but do you actually need them?